# ScrollView and text

Tags: android-studio

How can I make my screen scroll?

How to use ScrollView? At my activity, in it there is a picture and the text, it is necessary for me that at movement downwards or upwards the screen scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ScrollView` XML resource is fairly easy to use and powerful.  Just wrap whatever content you want to be scrollable in the XML with the `ScrollView` tags and the rest will be taken care of for you.  Simple example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/yourID"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

        ...
</LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

This example shows a `LinearLayout` filled with whatever you need (TextView in this case) that will scroll on screen when it has to.